# SQLAlchemy ManyToOne Relationship issue

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to connect two models.

Model #1 is called "Groups". It is connected to several "Teams" via starter_id, main_id, dessert_id. I want to have a field called "teams" which contains a list of all connected teams.

```
class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    starter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    main_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    dessert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'))

    #Relationships
    teams = db.relationship('Team', back_populates="group", foreign_keys= \
    [starter_1_id, starter_2_id, starter_3_id, main_1_id, main_2_id, main_3_id, \
    dessert_1_id, dessert_2_id, dessert_3_id])


class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.id'))

    # Relationships
    group = db.relationship("Group", back_populates="teams", foreign_keys=[group_id])
```

I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
between parent/child tables on relationship Group.teams - there are multiple
foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument,
providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a
foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I obviously don't know how to fix that error ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "a team belongs to a group" relationship (`Team.group`) and its inverse, "a group has many teams" (`Group.teams`), is given by the foreign key `Team.group_id`, so you need to write:

```
teams = db.relationship('Team', back_populates="group", foreign_keys=lambda: Team.group_id)
```

Comment: Thanks works fine. Can you give me some hints what the lambda does?

Comment: You need the `lambda` because you don't have the value `Team` at the time you define the relationship, because `Group` and `Team` each depend on the other for their definitions. SQLAlchemy supports passing a function for some of the parameters for `relationship` to resolve circular dependencies like this.